# CFArray created with CFCreateArray crashes when accessed

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, core-foundation, exc-bad-access

```
unsigned char _MyString[] = {0xda, 0xe5, 0x18, ..., 0x00};

CFArrayRef array = CFArrayCreate(NULL,
                               (const void**) CFStringCreateWithBytes(NULL,
                                                                      _MyString,
                                                                      sizeof(_MyString),
                                                                      kCFStringEncodingASCII,
                                                                      FALSE),
                               1,
                               &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

CFShow(arr); // <-- EXEC_BAD_ACCESS ERROR
```

The debugger shows its failing in

> CoreFoundation`CFGetTypeID:

Output from debugger

> __NSCFString
>
> (lldb)

I'm not sure where the memory error is, I think it must be due to the passing of the string in CFArrayCreate().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting the return value of CFStringCreateWithBytes to a const void ** is incorrect, which is why it's crashing. It's not a pointer to a pointer, it's a pointer to a CFString.

Comment: And the solution would be to store the CFString into another variable, then pass the pointer to that variable, since CFArrayCreate wants a pointer to storage containing `numValues` objects, and when you're creating an array of one object, a plain variable counts as storage containing one object.